# How to implement for loop in karate using feature files

Tags: karate

I want to call a feature file 15 times and each time output of previous call will go in next call's input

just as this loop use count's updated value in next iteration:

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
j=count+i;

count = count + 1;
}
```

Comment: What is your real life use case? You are calling the same feature file 15 times, in that case what will be the input to the first call as there is no preceding call? If the 15 is a static number, you can chain the request one after another in a single scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

```
* def result = call read('cat-create.feature') kittens
```

And `__loop` will be a built-in variable.